# Magento Static block with custom Module not Working After 1.9 ( from 1.3 ) Upgrade

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a static block in the home page that used to work in version 1.3

```
{{block type='extrss/feed' name='home_articles' template='rss/rss_main.phtml' feed_url='http://www.example.com/articles/feed/' item_count='9'}}
```

It displays nothing from the phtml in 1.9 , it doesn't error or anything even though error logging is on.

If I change the type to `core/template` - then the phtml displays , but the code doesn't seem to execute.

I'm a bit stuck!

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer.  I needed to go to `system->permissions->blocks` and give the static block permission to run.

Comment: As a means of preventing a form of internal highjack, this block permissions thing was introduced in 1.9.2.x and must be enabled for CMS blocks to be pulled into CMS pages and used. It's also an indicator that a very serious patch (not available for 1.3) was not applied to 1.4.2.x thru 1.9.1.1 and you might need to check the site for compromise clues.